# How to set height and width of iframe code which is inside textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox in which uers will paste the embed code of video.

Now i want to change the width and height according to me and also if there is no width or/and height property then it must be automatically added.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 15px;width:150px" align="right"> 
         <strong>IFrame Code:</strong>    
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 200px" align="left">
        <asp:TextBox Style="width: 250px;height: 50px" onblur="validate()" 
             ID="txturl" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" 
             TextMode="MultiLine">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend using a jQuery plugin (there are plenty).

take a look at [jQuery Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/).

hope that helps.

Comment: i want to change the height of that iframe which is inside textbox.

Comment: you can't put an iframe in a textbox

Comment: i am putting iframe code in the textbox and this code will be stored in database and on another page this code will be retrieved in "literal" text property.